# Expand inside card in cardListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, cardslib, android-cards

I am using cardslib to show expandable list of cards in cardListview, so the problem is when I tap on card it expands always at the bottom of the card but I want the card should expand inside my custom card layout(as shown in layout_home_item.xml).

I have referred cardslib documentation but couldn't able to figure it out.
below is the code suggested by @gabrielemariotti : to use

card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/layout_home_item"

```
 <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/layout_home_item"
    android:id="@+id/list" />
```

layout_home_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- A CardView that contains a TextView --><!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/read_more_img"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

**<FrameLayout                                 //inner expanded area
    android:id="@+id/card_content_expand_layout"
    style="@style/card.main_contentExpand"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/question_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>**

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/question_img"
    android:layout_below="@id/card_content_expand_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mat2"
    android:layout_height="270dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any actual code that shows how you create Card so it's hard to understand what you are doing.

Expand Card Inside or Outside is a new Card that you have to create and attach to your existing card. You can not achieve by just changing your layout of existing Card.

Here's how you can attach Inside Card to a Card.

```
Card card = new Card() // your actual Card
CardExpandInside expand = new CardExpandInside(context);
card.addCardExpand(expand);
```

You can see the example here https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/demo/stock/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/demo/fragment/nativeview/NativeCardExpandFragment.java
Look for this function in the file

```
init_custom_card_expand_inside()
```